# linq to object get element from list

Tags: asp.net, linq

```
List<PrpSubjects> objListSubjects  = _objSubjectDal.GetAllSubjects();
ddlSubjects.DataSource = objListSubjects;
ddlSubjects.DataBind();

_subjectName = objListSubjects...?
```

In `_subjectName` I want to fetch the subjectname from objListSubjects on basis of subjectid.
The subject list has subjectid and subjectname columns.

the question is i have a list with 2 columns subjectid,subjectname... the method returns a list of subject now i want to fetch the subjectname by subjectid,,, i thght instead of querying the database again i thght to use linq on list to fetch the subject name.. i hope i am clear about my requirement

Comment: dropdown... the question is i have a list<Subject> with 2 columns subjectid,subjectname... the method returns a list of subject now i want to fetch the subjectname by subjectid,,, i thght instead of querying the database again i thght to use linq on list to fetch the subject name.. i hope i am clear about my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_subjectName = objListSubjects.First(s => s.SubjectID == theIdYouAlreadyHave).SubjectName;
```

If you suspect that subject might not exist, you can use

```
objListSubjects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubjectID == id);
```

That will return `null` if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
_subjectName = objListSubjects
               .Where(s => s.SubjectId == someId)
               .Select(s => s.SubjectName)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

(will return `null` if there is no subject with the id `someId`)

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you find the sql style better to read ;)

```
_subjectName = (from s in objListSubjects 
               where s.SubjectId == someId 
               select s.SubjectName).FirstOrDefault();
```